# How to make buttons the same size and center all of them on the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and have 3 buttons of different sizes. I am trying to make them all the same size (based on the size of the largest one) and then center all of them in the middle of the page with space in between them. The buttons either end up not being the same size or not having any space in between them. I want the buttons to be dynamic so I don't want to make them conform to a certain px width.

Failed Attempt 1:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group blocks" data-toggle="buttons">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle Button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
  </div>
</div>

.blocks,
.btn {
  padding: 24px 12px;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

Failed Attempt 2:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 buttons-container">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default middle-btn">Middle Button</button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>

.btn {
  padding: 24px 12px !important;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
.blocks,
.btn {
  padding: 24px 12px;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 0;  
}

.blocks {width:100%;}

.btn {max-width:150px;width:100%;}

.container {
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

for attempt1: jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/Loxn91oq/4/
for attempt2: jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ogdfLq9c/